# How monitor the Coverage in Google Search Console by other tools or services?

Tags: google-search-console

I am trying to find out how to monitor the Coverage (Submitted and indexed/Indexed, not submitted in sitemap) in Google Search Console by some other tools or online services.

The reason why I am looking for the answer to this question is the lack of opportunities to track the whole history of how many pages were Validate day by date. Now the GSC gives the opportunities to Extract the Excsemplrs page report only for the past 6 days and see the Chart of Effected pages for the past 2 months...

All this kind of information after a while is rewriting with new by GSC.

If someone could share how he is dilling with this kind of issue and how he saves the information for future analyzing, I would appreciate that!

Right now I see only one way to save this kind of information, do it by hand ones in two months saves in excel file of Effected pages and download the report of Excsemplrs page every 6 days and transfer this kind of information to one excel file. This is only I could do with that....

I did search the online services where I may connect my GCS account by no one of them track this kind of metric.

Looking forward to getting some great solution - I hope there is something ))

P.S.
I have checked the GSC API there is no way to get this kind of info too.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!